# Source config file from .Renviron

Tags: r, environment-variables

I'd like to source a config file from my .Renviron file on R startup. Unfortunately I can't get it to work and don't find documentation handling that question.

Many packages we work with expect the same credentials to be in different positions / files and I do not want to introduce a 3rd place to change credentals. Also, I simply do not expect the .Renviron file to contain credentials nor does anyone in my company. So I'd like to do something in my .Renviron like this:

```
NO_PROXY=local.server,internal.tool,192.168.123.456
source ~/.cred/credentials
```

Is there a way I can source a file from .Renviron at startup to set additional env variables?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *from file `Renviron`* as that file *only stores `key=value` pairs* to be put into the environment.

You can, however, execute R statements and hence source code from `Rprofile`.

In both cases you can also use the local variants, i.e. `Renviron.site` or `Rprofile.site` and/or variants in your home directory. Full details are in `help(Startup)`.

Comment: Thank you! But that means, I'd have to add some kind of config-parser to the Rprofile. Maybe I won't get around that.

Comment: Maybe do it at the shell level instead?